# System of linear equations solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

Let suppose we have for all $x,y,z$ an identity given by:
$$xf(x,y,z)+yg(x,y,z)+zh(x,y,z)=0$$
If I have an equation
$$ax+by+cz=0$$ Does this imply that the coefficients of $x,y,z$ in both equations are proportional?
I mean assuming $abc\neq 0$
$$\dfrac{f(x,y,z)}{a}=\dfrac{g(x,y,z)}{b}=\dfrac{h(x,y,z)}{c}=\dfrac{p}{q}$$ where $\gcd(p,q)=1$

Comment: are $f, g, h$ linear? (Also in your first eq, you want $h$)

Comment: Not necessarily. But does it matter? i meant h. thanks.

Comment: Just realised it doesn't actually matter if they are linear

Comment: damn, you beat me to it :P I'm trying to think about this problem geometrically.